# I will examine you the first

Tags: grammar

How do you distinguish between these in written and oral speech:

***I will examine you the first. = I will be the first one to examine you.***

***I will examine you the first. = You will be the first one to be examined by me.***

Comment: In speech, it would depend on whether the speaker put an emphasis on "I" or "you".

Comment: The definite article sounds at best unusual here. The more idiomatic "I will examine you first" surely defaults to the "I will examine you before drawing any conclusions"  sense. I'd say the second place goes to "You are the first person that I will examine". _Then_ the "I will be the first [doctor] to examine you" sense. But physical context and/or textual context, and as Kate says, in speech, emphasis, will disambiguate.

Answer (score 2):

As @sarahbowman notes, you shouldn't say "the" before "first". We put "the" before a noun or noun phrase, not before an adverb.

But to your question: The sentence "I will examine you first" is ambiguous. It could mean, "I will be the first person to examine you", or it could mean, "You will be the first person that I examine." If which meaning is intended is not clear from the context, then you should word the statement differently to make it clear.

Comment: It could mean a third thing: "Examination will be the first thing I do with you."

Comment: @CanadianYankee True.

Answer (score 1):

Let me clarify: We don't need the definite article in this sentence; it should read:

> I will examine you first.

I know this means that I will be the first to be examined by you because you say so very clearly.

Subject: I

Verb: will examine

Object: you

Adverb: first

The subject does things to the object; the object cannot do things to the subject of the sentence.

The following is incorrect:

> I will examine you the first. = I will be the first one to examine
> you.

If you will be the first to examine me, that means there must be at least one more person who will examine me but I may not be the first person you examine. Thus, you must not say "I will examine you first." You must say "I will be the first to examine you."

Subject: I

Verb: will be

Adjective completing Subject: first to examine you

Answer (score 0):

Emphasis.

> *I* will examine you first (then somebody else will examine you).
> I will examine *you* first (then move onto examining others).
> I will examine you *first* (then do something else).

If you were reporting the speech, you could use italics, or you could add context, for example

> The professor looked at Charlotte "I will examine you first," he said. To me he added "Wait outside, and have a last look over your revision notes."